# In an expect script, how do you allow the interact return string to print to STDOUT?

Tags: bash, tcl, expect

Example would help:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect

spawn $env(SHELL)
expect "\$ "
interact KILL return
send "exit\r"
expect eof
```

So in the above, when it gives control to me via interact, I can issue any command I want.  But if I start to type "KILL", it seems `expect` takes over STDOUT, so I can't see what I'm typing.  It works as expected, otherwise.

But I'd like to also be able to see what I'm typing, when I'm typing "KILL"

Am I missing something simple from the manual?  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#!/usr/bin/expect

spawn $env(SHELL)
expect "\$ "
interact -nobuffer KILL return
send "exit\r"
expect eof
```

interact -nobuffer

That seems to do it. :)